# Loss values in a Domain Adversarial

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, domain-adaptation

I have been using ResNet-50 with Domain-Adversarial network. I observed an oscillation in the loss values from the evaluation as you can see in the figures, this oscillation was not observed when using ResNet-50 without Domain-Adversarial. I am wondering why is this happening?

With Domain-Adversarial:
[image]

[image]

Without Domain adversarial:

[image]

[image]

Thanks.